# Autogenerate cases for a switch. Or another suggestion

Tags: c++, if-statement, macros, switch-statement, auto-generate

Is there any way to autogenerate cases if necessary (with certain logic described by example) for a switch? Or maybe you have another suggestion. `some code` is always the same.

```
    int num = 0; // Global variable
    .
    .
    . 
    switch (num)
    {
    case 0:
    {
        //some code
        num++;
        break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        if (CHECK(1)) // CHECK is macros for comparing 
        {
            //some code
            num++;
        }
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        if (CHECK(1) && CHECK(2))
        {
            //some code
            num++;
        }
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        if (CHECK(1) && CHECK(2) && CHECK(3))
        {
            //some code
            num++;
        }
        break;
    }
    case 4 ...
```

... and so on

Comment: Sounds like a XY-problem. What are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: *`(CHECK(1)) // CHECK is macros for comparing`* – in addition to πάντα ῥεῖs question: comparing *what*?

Comment: "int num = 0; // Global variable" - try *hard* to *avoid* global variables. Trust me, they are going to give you so much grief in the long run that it's not even funny (and yes, singletons go in that bucket as well).

Comment: + with every global, a kitty dies :(  //edit: really!!

Comment: Is `some code` always the same?

Comment: Quentin, yes, some code is always the same.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're doing something fishy inside `CHECK`, it should be as easy as a `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= num; ++i)
    if(!CHECK(i))
        return;

// some code
++num;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can generate whatever code you need, stick it in a file, and then `#include` the generated file wherever needed in your source file.

Doing that can *sometimes* be a good idea and sometimes a *horrible* idea. It all depends on your code/problem/circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I have proposed using templates in this case.

```
template <int level>
bool check()
{
   return CHECK(level) && check<level - 1>();
}

template <>
bool check<0>() { return true;}

template <int level>
void caseCheck(int& num)
{
   if (num == level)
   {
      if (check<level>())
      // some code
      num++;
   }
   else
      caseCheck<level - 1>(num);
}

template <>
void caseCheck<0>(int& num)
{
   // some code
   num++;
}


caseCheck<NUM_CASES>(num);
```